# Does Excel run queries in order?

Tags: excel

I have the following 2 queries from SQL Server.  Is it guaranteed that Query1 will always execute before Query2?  Namely when I hit the refresh button.  I am updating a table in Query1 so I want that to run first before Query2 runs.  Let me know if this is bad practice.

[image]

Comment: Please, if you must use images, don't show us a massive screen of blank images... crop the image down to the useful part. Also the question is not relevant to SQL Server, its purely an Excel question.

Comment: If you use Data from Query1 (maybe a join) in your Query2, PQ will compleatly run the code from Query1 to calculate the results for Query2. So ist is not neccessary to run Query1 first.

Answer (score 0):

Open Power Query and click View > Query Dependencies. If they have any kind of dependency it will be shown in this visual. If they don't, the order of execution is not important and it doesn't matter whether one is executed first.

Comment: You can change the dependencies so that Q2 is after Q1?  Looks like they are not in order right now and query 1 is not pointing to query 2 to signify that 2 is after 1.

Comment: @bakalolo You can force the refreshing order with VBA: `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query1").Refresh` and then `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query2").Refresh`. But if the queries have an intrinsic dependency, such as when a formula in a certain cell is dependent on another, there is nothing to be done, since the order of execution of each one is pre-established in this dependency.